# RSpec with Rails(3.2) and Mongoid / Unexpected behaviour.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid

I have a rails(3.2) app working with MongoDB using Mongoid.

I'm trying to test that a record would update it's updated_at field when I make changes, something simple like:

```
  it "Should modify updated_at when we make changes to a record" do  
    record = create(:record)  
    previous_updated_at = record.updated_at
    record.touch    
    expect(record.updated_at).not_to eq(previous_updated_at)
  end
```

The test wont pass, unless I add sleep(1). Something like:

```
  it "Should modify updated_at when we make changes to a record" do  
    record = create(:record)  
    previous_updated_at = record.updated_at
    sleep(1)
    record.touch    
    expect(record.updated_at).not_to eq(previous_updated_at)
  end
```

I'm sure there is a work around for this. Please note that you can check out my spec_helper.rb at:  https://gist.github.com/eqbal/1a4d96a0e761eb0faf22.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade Mongoid gem to version "~> 3.0.1".

Then I had to set the database session options `consistency: :strong, safe: true`, neither of which are the default to ensure that you can always immediately read back the data you just wrote using Mongoid.